# Are framing questions on topic?

Tags: support, questions, on-topic

I have a question about mounting physical photographs in frames. Is that on topic here?

I'm doing the framing myself and I can also probably put it on Arts & Crafts, but I'm curious if it works here too, since it's kind of a presentation thing.

Comment: In general I’d say yes, but, what’s the question to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as long as you are framing a photograph.

However, you'll get better expertise here if the question is directly related to something about the photograph itself — either to do with matching the contents to the frame, or about the materials of the print, or something like that. If the question is about, say, making a perfect miter joint, Arts & Crafts may be better.

You note that your question is "kind of a presentation thing", so that's likely perfect for here.

Comment: Ah, the perfect miter joint. So simple in design, so terribly hard to execute.